# What is the registry location of windows vista search history?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, registry

Hi what is the search history location in vista? I need to get it programmaticaly. I know that in other windowses, its in:

windows xp/2000

```
* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Search Assistant\ACMru\5603
```

Windows 98

```
* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Doc Find Spec MRU
```

Windows 7

```
* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\WordWheelQuery
```

But cant find anywhere vista location.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: I thought about `belongs on superuser.com` but I guess this could be programming related.